# How to update to the particular revision in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: c#, winforms, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on utility creation. I have to update the particular revision of source programatically. Please suggest me your ideas.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a Java project ? Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Why is tortoise svn relevant? Just use the [svn command line arguments](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html)

Comment: @TechDog, it is tagged as C#... Can you elaborate a bit more - what ideas exactly are you seeking?It is not so clear.

Comment: You want to "Checkout particular version" or "Update to particular version"?

Comment: i need to "update to particular revison"

Answer (score 1):

I do not think version control management like svn would allow  **"Update to particular version"**, Because changes(commits)  are meant to be stored as versions.

Making changes to a particular version breaks the core principle of version control management, So I do not think there can be a way to **"Update to particular version"**

You may checkout particular version...

If you want to do update via program...pls refer to the below link..
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html

Also have a look at the following link for updating working copy:-
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.update

**Command :-**

```
SVN Update
```

**Examples**

```
 svn update

A    newdir/toggle.c
A    newdir/disclose.c
A    newdir/launch.c
D    newdir/README
Updated to revision 32.
```

You can also “update” your working copy to an older revision..

```
svn update -r30
A    newdir/README
D    newdir/toggle.c
D    newdir/disclose.c
D    newdir/launch.c
U    foo.c
Updated to revision 30.
```

Comment: Hi @TechDog, Actually i have done to update the svn by code

Comment: `Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:update /path:" + updateLocation + "/";
proc.Start();
'

Comment: Now i want to update to particular revision as shown in above image. Which command can i use and how to give that particular revision details? Please suggest me any ideas.

Comment: Have a look in to this https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html

Comment: Hi @TechDog , i have already tried you suggested. But i don't know how to give the choosen revision details in that command line. 'svn update [-r rev] [-depth ARG] [--ignore-externals] PATH`

Comment: I tried this `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:update [-r 523174] [-depth ARG] [--ignore-externals] /path:" + updateLocation + "/";`

Comment: but how can i handle [-depth] and [-r]?

Comment: Hi, This code `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:update /rev:523174 /path:" + updateLocation + "/";` is works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to get the revision numbers between two dates . I tried this `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:log /path:" + updateLocation +"/" /startrev:"{"2016-12-19"}" /endrev:"{"2016-11-11"}" ;` but it does not working. Please is there any other possible?